# when i try add a unique word end of $domain

Tags: php, html

I have a code its format:

```
<keyFile>/root/.acme.sh/$domain.$tld/$domain.$tld.key</keyFile>
```

And its add this for example:

```
/root/.acme.sh/test.com/test.com.key
```

Now i want it add this (_ecc end of domain), so i added _ecc end of code:

```
/root/.acme.sh/test.com_ecc/test.com.key
```

But it show me this error:
Global symbol "$domain_ecc" requires explicit package name at /var/www/html/addnewxmlsub line 17

As _ecc is unique, i want know how i should add _ecc at end of domain it works correct, cause now it think _ecc is some of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: About what lib/framework you are talking?